# How do I format date 'Apr 2, 2019' to `YYYY-MM-DD` without a warning?

Tags: momentjs

When I try to parse date:  'Apr 2, 2019', got a warning:

> "Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized…   at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:672:32)"

Here is my code:

```js
var now = moment('Apr 2, 2019').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
console.log(now) // "2019-04-02"
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

I get the correct result, but there is a warning. How do I format this date to `YYYY-MM-DD` without warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Apr 2, 2019` is a valid literal date string, you can do it by wrapping `Apr 2, 2019` in `new Date()`.

```js
var now = moment(new Date('Apr 2, 2019')).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
console.log(now) // "2019-04-02"
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Here are some test cases.
https://codesandbox.io/s/wzqo6k0k25

---

Another method is to specify what date string format are you passing in so moment know how to parse it reliably.

```js
var now = moment('Apr 2, 2019', 'MMM D, YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
console.log(now) // "2019-04-02"
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

You can find the date format tokens in the [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

For more technical details about why this is happening, you can check out the [issue on github](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407).

Comment: But why `moment` throw a warning?

Comment: It's because there may be chances where the parsing may be done incorrectly in that format. Another way is to specify what kind of date string format you're passing in. I will update the answer.